# Why Xcode 9 creates my outlet (strong, nonatomic) by default

Tags: ios, xcode, iboutlet

When I control-drag outlet from the storyboard, I got the strong property by default. I'm using **Xcode 9.4.1**. The following code is what it looks like. Is it because of XCode Swift compatibility as in Swift it makes sense to create *strong*.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value should be `weak`, but if you once change it manually to strong as shown in the photo, the default value changes to strong, so you need to manually put it back to weak.

[image]

Comment: Cool explanation :)